# send post request to website via php (similar to xmlhttprequest)

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest, request

I was wondering, in php is it possible to send a post request to another site without forms (just parameters) like xmlhttprequest in javascript? If so how would it be possible? i'd appreciate some examples. I think it's with curl, so in this case, how would i send the following parameters:
name=bob&lastname=tim via post request to www.example.com using curl in php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fields_string = "name=bob&lastname=tim";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```